# How does HBeAg change to Anti-HBe in acute hepatitis

Tags: microbiology, antibody, antigen, hepatitis

I am thinking this figure

[image]

which can also be drawn like this

[image]

**How does HBeAg change to Anti-HBe?**

There are some triggers that stimulate Anti-HBe production after HBeAg level is done. 
I think they can Anti-HBc.
There must be other mechanisms too.

Comment: Can you please introduce your abbreviations? This would be a good style so people can understand the figures better.

Comment: Alan answered the question. Just standard antigens and antibodies for HBV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I have understood the question but ...

HbeAg is a secreted variant of HbcAg (the core antigen of HBV). Unlike HbcAg, HbeAg is found in the blood. I believe that it is produced as a result of a splice variant of the corresponding RNA.

The phenomenon described in these Figures is an example of [seroconversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seroconversion). Before seroconversion the antigen is detectable in the blood but there is no antibody directed against it; after seroconversion there is antibody but no antigen.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer! You understood what I mean. I missed the term seroconversion. I think there are actually two windows periods and two  seroconversions in the figure. First, for HBe and then for HBs. I would like to know how these two seroconversion stages and/or windows stages differ. It would be nice to use some analogous words like "isovolumetric contraction" and "isovolumetric relaxation" just to differentiate some property between the two window periods. I do not know which property that can be.